# Standard Deviation in dataset for Classification with `for` loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I did the windowing operation in a data set.
Now I calculate the average of each window according to the following code:
windoing :

```
def moving_window(x, length, step=1):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step+43) for stream, i in zip( streams,it.count(step=step))])
x_=list(moving_window(x,90))
x_=np.asarray(x_)
print(x_)
```

Calculate the average:

```
def mean(dataset):
    return sum(dataset) / len(dataset)
listt=[]
for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    listt.append(mean(x_[i]))
print(listt)
```

I want to get the standard deviation of each window.Like the average.
But I can not
I wrote the following code:

```
for i in range(len(x_)):
    listt1=[]
    listt.append(std(x_[i])) 
print(listt1)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question, you say you cannot write some code, why?

Comment: Question is about `statistics`, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Comment: Maybe provide expected result given example data, so we can better comprehend idea of windowing standard deviation.

Comment: I want to calculate the error deviation, but the code I typed has an error and does not calculate the value.